# MySQL with JDBC - useUnicode needed?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

In a lot of places, it is noted that if you want to use JDBC with MySQL and have support for UTF-8, you need to add `useUnicode=true` in the JDBC URL.

E.g.:

- [JDBC MySQL UTF-8 string writing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405236/jdbc-mysql-utf-8-string-writing-problem)
- [problem with utf8 in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689381/problem-with-utf8-in-java)

However, I tried this locally using MySQL 5.7.19 on Mac OS X with mysql-connector-java 5.1.41 (pulled in by Spring Boot 1.5.3). I added a file `/etc/my.cnf` with:

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

This makes sure MySQL is set up for UTF-8:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                     |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now in my `application.properties` I tried with:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
```

and

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=true
```

But in both cases, it seems to be ok. So: is the advice to add `useUnicode=true` still valid?

Comment: "But in both cases, it seems to be ok.". What's the "it" that seemed to be okay?

Comment: Storing and retrieving text in a `TEXT` MySQL column that has international characters like ř, á, ý, ž, ...

Comment: There indeed is a redundancy in MySQL. AFAIK the URL setting is for the JDBC driver at the client communicating the textual data in UTF-8. Whether SET NAMES is equivalent, or what exactly happens - _no idea._

Comment: Moreover, according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html it is `true` by default anyway.

Comment: `useUnicode` is no longer present in configuration properties for [MySQL Connector/J 8.0(.18)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#connector-j-reference-set-config) and the only place where it is mentioned is in the context of versions prior to 8.0.13 : [How can I use 3-byte UTF8 with Connector/J?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html)